# Whats the difference between usage and arguments in npm commander?

Tags: javascript, npm, node-commander

I'm looking at the [npm package commander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander) and the **readme** doesn't seem to provide me enough of a description to distinguish the `program.usage()` and `program.arguments()` option.

Can anyone provide a clear description on their purpose, how to use them and how they differ?

Thanks

Comment: `usage` displays usage information. `arguments` describes arguments that should be provided to the CLI. Edit: the latter informs the parser; the former is simply displayed to the user.

Comment: @FissureKing Thanks for making this clear. Just saw the output of --help option and saw that the .usage appears there.